# Nextflow - I/O and index issues

Tags: groovy, dsl, nextflow

I am new to nextflow and am trying to build a pipeline. I am having trouble with passing outputs into new processes, properly capturing outputs, and with BWA-MEM2 index designation.

Here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow
// Declare syntax version
nextflow.enable.dsl = 2

// Set parameters
params.fastq = "$projectDir/fastq/*_{1,2}.f*"
params.refgenome = "$projectDir/RefGenome/hg38.fa"

workflow {

    read_pairs_ch = Channel.fromFilePairs(params.fastq, checkIfExists: true) 

    trimAndQC(read_pairs_ch)
    readMapping(params.refgenome, trimAndQC.out.trimmedreads)
}

process trimAndQC {
    debug true
    tag "$sample_id"

    publishDir 'trimmed/', mode: 'copy', overwrite: false

    input:
    tuple val(sample_id), path(fastq)

    output:
    tuple val('sample_id'), path('*_val_1.fq.gz'), path('*_val_2.fq.gz'), emit: trimmedreads

    shell:
    """
    trim_galore --paired --fastqc ${fastq.get(0)} ${fastq.get(1)}
    """
}

// BWA read mapping
process readMapping {
    debug true
    tag "$sample_id"

    publishDir 'bwa_aligned/', mode: 'copy', overwrite: false

    input:
    path(refgenome)
    tuple val(sample_id), val(trimmedreads)

    output:
    path('${sample_id}_sorted.bam'), emit: sorted_bam

    script:
    def indexbase = refgenome.baseName
    
    """
    bwa-mem2 mem -t 2 '${indexbase}' '${trimmedreads}' | samtools sort -@2 -o '${sample_id}_sorted.bam' -
    """
}
```

First, I am getting this warning:

```
WARN: Input tuple does not match input set cardinality declared by process `readMapping` -- offending value: [sample_id, /Users/me/Desktop/fastq/work/27/448a89259a9435ff86d52009afa05d/SRR925811_1_val_1.fq.gz, /Users/me/Desktop/fastq/work/27/448a89259a9435ff86d52009afa05d/SRR925811_2_val_2.fq.gz]
```

Which is confusing as my output is a tuple and thus should match the cardinality of the output of `trimAndQC`. As an aside, I have noticed most scripts passing the input tuple (in this case `path(fastq)`) as a single argument, but to get the command to work I have to use the `.get()` accession method to 'unpack' the tuple, so I am unsure what I am doing wrong there.

Second, I am getting this error in regards to the output of `readMapping` process:

```
ERROR ~ Error executing process > 'readMapping (sample_id)'

Caused by:
  Missing output file(s) `${sample_id}_sorted.bam` expected by process `readMapping (sample_id)`

Command executed:

  bwa-mem2 mem -t 2 'hg38' '/Users/me/Desktop/fastq/work/27/448a89259a9435ff86d52009afa05d/SRR925811_1_val_1.fq.gz' | samtools sort -@2 -o sample_id_sorted.bam -

Command exit status:
  0

Command output:
  (empty)
```

I assume this may be due to the cardinality warning above and `sample_id` is empty.

Finally, I cannot seem to designate the index properly to the BWA-MEM2 command. The error:

```
Command error:
  Looking to launch executable "/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/envs/nextflow/bin/bwa-mem2.sse42", simd = .sse42
  Launching executable "/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/envs/nextflow/bin/bwa-mem2.sse42"
  -----------------------------
  Executing in SSE4.2 mode!!
  -----------------------------
  * SA compression enabled with xfactor: 8
  * Ref file: hg38
  * Entering FMI_search
  ERROR! Unable to open the file: hg38.bwt.2bit.64

Work dir:
  /Users/me/Desktop/fastq/work/23/f8b3b6eace6f11f8619ce435b16725

Tip: you can try to figure out what's wrong by changing to the process work dir and showing the script file named `.command.sh`

 -- Check '.nextflow.log' file for details
```

In my RefGenome directory I have hg38.fa indexed on an AWS EC2 and downloaded to locally to prototype the pipeline. The files look have these extensions:
`hg38.fa.{0123,amb,ann,pac,bwt.2bit.64}` and appear to work fine if I just run the `bwa-mem2 mem` command in my terminal.

I have tried to adapt multiple SO answers (e.g., [how to chain Channel.fromFilePairs from one process to another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77320015/how-to-chain-channel-fromfilepairs-from-one-process-to-another-process), [nextflow: how to pass directory path with files created in process before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76493667/nextflow-how-to-pass-directory-path-with-files-created-in-process-before)), I have gone through the EMBL training ([Nextflow](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/training/online/courses/nextflow/)), looked through pipelines on nf-core and github, and have spent time with nextflow documentation prior to asking this question. I seem to be misunderstanding some inherent principle of nextflow so any advice on what to focus would be appreciated.

Finally, for clarity and reproducibility I am using the following fastqs from NCBI SRA ([SRX317818](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra/?term=SRR925811)) for prototyping. These are the versions of nextflow, trim-galore, and bwa-mem2 I am using all via an Anconda environment:

```
bwa-mem2                  2.2.1                hdf58011_5    bioconda
nextflow                  23.10.1              hdfd78af_0    bioconda
trim-galore               0.6.10               hdfd78af_0    bioconda
```

---

I have crossposted this question on Biostars ([Nextflow - I/O and index issues](https://www.biostars.org/p/9586656/)). Based on this post, it appears crossposting is tolerated to a degree ([Is cross-posting a question...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)). I can remove the post if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @dthorbur at Biostars for his help with this problem.

---

I have finally completely resolved all my problems and want to document here in case anyone else runs into such issues in the future.

First problem was issues with cardinality. As @dthorbur pointed out, my issue was not keeping the same tuple structure between processes. The output from the upstream process:

```
output:
tuple val('sample_id'), path('*_val_1.fq.gz'), path('*_val_2.fq.gz')
```

Whereas the input into the downstream process:

```
input:
tuple val(sample_id), val(trimmedreads)
```

Resulting in an easy fix:

```
input:
tuple val(sample_id), path(read1), path(read2)
```

Next issue I was having was ingesting the index for BWA into my working environment. I found the most straightforward and simple method was to designate the index directory and fasta file separately like this:

```
// Set paths for index directory and the reference fasta
params.index_dir = "$projectDir/RefGenome/BWAIndex"
params.ref = "hg38.fa"
------------------------
...
// Designate the index within the processes like this
script:
"""
bwa mem -t 2 ${index_dir}/${ref} ${read1} ${read2} | samtools sort -@2 -o "${sample_id}_sorted.bam" -
"""
------------------------

// Define the channels and pass them to the process
index_ch = Channel.fromPath(params.index_dir)
ref_ch = Channel.of(params.ref)
...
bwa_align(index_ch, ref_ch, trim_QC.out.trimmed_reads)
```

My final problem was getting the bwa_align process to run properly. My original error was related to no output file, which I realized was an issue with single quotes around the output file and within the script block:

```
output:
path('${sample_id}_sorted.bam')
```

which Nextflow wasn't interpreting properly. Once I switched to double quotes all was fine. So I am tempted to strictly use double quotes when writing Nextflow scripts.

Here is my final script that finally worked:

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow
nextflow.enable.dsl = 2

// Define parameters
params.fastq = "$projectDir/fastq/*_{1,2}*"
params.index_dir = "$projectDir/RefGenome/BWAIndex"
params.ref = "hg38.fa"

workflow {

    fastq_ch = Channel.fromFilePairs(params.fastq)
    index_ch = Channel.fromPath(params.index_dir)
    ref_ch = Channel.of(params.ref)

    trim_QC(fastq_ch)
    bwa_align(index_ch, ref_ch, trim_QC.out.trimmed_reads)
}

process trim_QC {
    debug true
    tag "$sample_id"

    publishDir 'trimmed/', mode: 'copy', overwrite: false

    input:
    tuple val(sample_id), path(fastq)

    output:
    tuple val("${sample_id}"), path("*_val_1.fq.gz"), path("*_val_2.fq.gz"), emit: trimmed_reads

    script:
    def (read1, read2) = fastq
    """
    trim_galore --paired --fastqc ${read1} ${read2}
    """
}

process bwa_align {
    debug true
    tag "$sample_id"

    publishDir 'bwa_aligned/', mode: 'copy', overwrite: false

    input:
    path index_dir
    val ref
    tuple val(sample_id), path(read1), path(read2)

    output:
    path("${sample_id}_sorted.bam"), emit: sorted_bam

    script:
    """
    bwa mem -t 2 ${index_dir}/${ref} ${read1} ${read2} | samtools sort -@2 o "${sample_id}_sorted.bam" -
    """
}
```

Comment: Ha, thanks for giving me a nod on Biostars. I forgot to say, there is a nextflow slack set up by the devs. It's pretty good for most problems, though a little harder to follow in my experience.

Comment: Thanks again @dthorbur, I'll check out the slack channel with any future problems as well.